# Ionic background audio when app is closed when when using Web Audio API

Tags: ios, audio, ionic-framework, web-audio-api

Building a metronome application and using Web Audio API / AudioContext.

Currently, when closing the app / locking the phone the audio is stopped. Is there any way I can get this to run in the background when locked / another app is open?

Reference of the schedular I am using to wrap around the API:

https://github.com/mohayonao/web-audio-scheduler

In Xcode I have checked Background Modes > Audio but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this link will help you to achieve your requirement

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode